# Creating video from images using Microsoft media foundation

Tags: winapi, video, ms-media-foundation

Is there a way to create video of pre defined duration from a set of images using Microsoft media foundation?

Say for example, I have 50 images, can Is there a way to use those 50 images and create a video of say 50 seconds or 100 seconds ?

Answer (score 2):

[Sink Writer API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/sink-writer) is exactly for this.

[image]
<sub>(source: [s-msft.com](https://i-msdn.sec.s-msft.com/dynimg/IC500905.png))</sub>

You set it up and start feeding with images (such as RGB data) and associated time data. The respectively configured API will create a pipeline to accept images, convert and encode them as necessary, write into file such as MP4.

MSDN article links tutorial at the bottom of the page. You will find other questions on StackOverflow which also reference this tutorial.

Comment: Thank you so much. Im new to c++, can you please tell me more on how to feed with images (such as RGB data) part ?

Comment: @sharathvignesh: There is a tutorial for beginners at the bottom of linked MSDN article.